# returning a variable from the callback of a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the following functions:

```
function loop_perms(permissions) {
.... call check_perm here....
}
function check_perm(perm) {
        var result;
        FB.api(
         {
            method: 'users.hasAppPermission',
            ext_perm: perm
         }, function(response) {
            result = response;
         });
         return result;
    }
```

Now, the issue is that I am getting an `undefined` from the result of `check_perm` whereas in the Firebug console, I can see that `response` has a value of 0 or 1 (depending on perm)

Anyone knows what I am doing wrong? I am guessing it has something to do with the fact that i am trying to capture the value of a variable inside a callback.

Regards
Nikhil Gupta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume the Facebook API is asynchronous. So at the time `return result` is executed, the callback was not called yet. You have to provide a callback from the calling function:

```
function check_perm(perm, callback) {
    var result;
    FB.api(
     {
        method: 'users.hasAppPermission',
        ext_perm: perm
     }, callback);
}
```

and

```
function loop_perms(permissions) {
    check_perm(whatever here, function(result) {
        // do something with result
    });
}
```

Comment: so lets say this `loop_perms` function is also being called from some other function and that function deals with the result of `loop_perms`, I need to insert a callback to the `loop_perms` function  as well? and so on? if yes, is there a way to disable asynchronous calls on FB.api and not FB.init() as a whole (i'm unsure here)

Comment: You need to make a complete break in your code flow, cut `loop_perms` into two halfs, one before calling `check_perm` and one after, which should be used as the return function given to `FB.api`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're calling `FB.api` asychronously, passing it an anonymous function as a callback that gives `result` a value.  `check_perm` is returning **before** the callback is executed, at which point `result` is still undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Problem 1: result is readable by the callback, but it is a copy so not writeable in the way you're thinking. (writeable locally not globally, this sub-problem could be "fixed" by making it a global variable, but it still wouldn't make your code work)

Problem 2: FB.api most likely calls that callback asynchronously in the future letting check_perm return immediately with result in whatever state it currently is in (undefined)

You need to put the code that deals with the actual response inside that callback function to be executed when then response is available. You wouldn't even need the result variable at that point.

Comment: Problem 1: That is just wrong, given JavaScript scoping there is only one `result` variable, residing in the scope of `check_perm`, and both readable and writeable by the inner function. If only the inner function were called before the outer function returned this would be perfectly legit.