# callback on a variable which is inside a .each() loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, callback

I have this function, which is doing an asynchronous call to FB.api method.
Now, i am looping over some data and capturing result of the above method call successfully.
However, I am using a `.each` loop and I really can not figure out how to place my callback in this method, so that the outer method is only executed once.

Here are the functions I am using:

```
ask_for_perms($(this).val(),function(result) {
  $('#some-div').html('<a onclick = "get_perms(result);" >get perms</a>');
});
function ask_for_perms(perms_requested,cb) {
    var request = [];
    $.each(perms_requested,function(i,permission) {
        FB.api({
            method: 'users.hasAppPermission',
            ext_perm: permission
            }, function(response) {
            if (response == 0) request.push(permission);
            request.join(',');
            cb(request); // cb is called many times here.
        });
    });
}
```

I am trying to return the `request` string from `ask_for_perms` function.
Can anyone suggest me on where to place a proper callback to `ask_for_perms`. Right now, however, it works for me, but the callback is being called many times since it is inside a for loop.

referencing: [returning a variable from the callback of a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4531933/returning-a-variable-from-the-callback-of-a-function)

Comment: I think you need to pass `request` into the `.each()` callback as it is out of scope inside that function although I'm not sure of this.

Comment: `request` variable is accessible inside `.each()`, however `request.join(',')` is outside the `FB.api` method's callback and hence, is `undefined` at the time of return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you FB calls are asynchronous and you call cb(request) before they are able to execute their callbacks.  Try checking for the last requested response, then calling your cb function:

```
function ask_for_perms(perms_req,cb) {
    var request = [];
    $.each(perms_req,function(i,req) {
        FB.api({
            method: 'users.hasAppPermission',
            ext_perm: req
            }, function(response) {
            console.log(req + ' | ' + response);
            if (response == 0) {
                request.push(req);
                if(i == perms_req.length-1) //true if last item in array
                    cb(request.join(','));
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: `if(i == perms_req.length-1) cb(request.join(','));` is what I was missing ... really really thank you :)